# clone with CLONE_VM will change the tid in Multithreading?

Tags: linux, multithreading, clone

```
#include "myapue.h"

#define SYSTEM_STACKSIZE 8192

pthread_t ntid;
struct mypthread {
    void *pidding[26];
    pid_t tid;
    pid_t pid;
};

int __system_proc(void *pArgs)
{
    (void)execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", (char *)pArgs, (char *)NULL);
    return 0;
}

long mysystem(const char *pcStr)
{
    long status;
    pid_t pid;

    char tmpstack[SYSTEM_STACKSIZE];
    void **newstack;

    newstack = (void **)(void *)(unsigned long)(SYSTEM_STACKSIZE + tmpstack);
    *--newstack = (void *)pcStr;

    pid = clone(__system_proc, newstack,
                CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | SIGCHLD, (void *)pcStr); 
    if (pid < 0)
    {       
        err_sys("clone fail: %s", strerror(pid));
    }

    (void)waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL /*__WCLONE*/);

    return status;
}

void *thr_fn(void *arg)
{
    pid_t tid;

    printf("new thread\n");
    ntid = pthread_self();
    tid = ((struct mypthread *)ntid)->tid;
    printf("this is ntid[%x], tid[%lu] before system\n", (unsigned int)ntid, (unsigned long)tid);
    mysystem("touch test");
    ntid = pthread_self();
    tid = ((struct mypthread *)ntid)->tid;
    printf("this is ntid[%x], tid[%lu] after system\n", (unsigned int)ntid, (unsigned long)tid);
    sleep(60);
    return((void *)0);
}

int main(void)
{
    int err;

    err = pthread_create(&ntid, NULL, thr_fn, NULL);
    if (0 != err)
    {
        err_quit("Can't creat thread: %s\n", strerror(err));
    }

    printf("main thread\n");
    sleep(60);

    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to use the **clone** simulation system function **system**, but when I found out after calling **mysystem**, that pthread_kill function can not be used, always returned to fail, so I wrote the above routines,Found after calling  **mysystem** thread tid became 0XFFFFFFF (lead pthread_kill reason for the failure to return),
However, if I remove CLONE_VM flag in the call clone, the result is normal.
I would like to ask you, CLONE_VM why will lead tid been tampered with?

My system is ubuntu14.04 with libc2.18, very thanks!

I am a student in china, my English is so poor, there must be Many grammatical errors. I am so sorry!